# My launcher / client crashes when I connect to my local FTB server. I can connect to public servers fine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-direwolf20

This came about when I was trying to move the files below into a new area on my computer, I have moved them back since but the problem still arises, when I try and log into my locally hosted mincraft server I get a crash just after the "logging in", Logs below.
[image]

What I have tried.

> I did try the [Trouble Shooting Steps Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17__CctJokfTCXovBs5YIdRhG39tdZlLMI_Mfq_aMu3k/edit), and I thought it worked, It gave me a flash of my character, but then crashed again. (This involved a complete re install along with java.)
>
> I have tried connecting to a public Direwolf20 server and it **worked fine.** It seems to just be connecting to my local server.
>
> I have tried updating my server ( I have not completely wiped it yet as I do not want to lose the save file)

I asked my friend to try and connect and he could connect and play but I cannot.I'm at my wits end I've tried and searched everything I could think of.

**http://pastebin.com/XwPdBLaf**

I really appreciate you looking over this I know it's not all that fun. All I can do is thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure people on FTB forums are more likely to answer that...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because technical support for modded minecraft is not supported here.

Comment: Digging deep for this one @TimS.!

Comment: Actually, it was me who did the "digging deep" and flagged the question. The thing is, off-topic questions are still off-topic five years later.

Comment: Where exactly are the rules which says technical support is not supported?

Comment: Technical support for *modded* minecraft is off topic. If not, we would get hundreds or thousands of questions per day, most of which can never be answered because of the broad scope of why modded minecraft installations won't work.

Comment: @jackdh The list of off-topic stuff can be found here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was something in my inventory that was causing me to dc, I deleted my user from the files and I could relog in back fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you go onto your server and host it on the same computer the CPU can sometimes bottleneck because you can sometimes have too much stuff open in the ram but the CPU can't process it all and theoretically there should be someway of stopping that because all your server is doing is rendering the game once and you are rendering the game again so it is just using double (or there abouts) the resources to run. Note the Server won't use your GPU unless specified that is the only difference between the two.

I know there is a way to port-forward a LAN server which would be the best thing because then you aren't loading two instances of the same game and you would be able to play lag free, If you can play LAN already

Answer (score 0):

This could be your problem:

```
Memory: 589475320 bytes (562 MB) / 1479016448 bytes (1410 MB) up to 1908932608 bytes (1820 MB)
```

Minecraft is RAM-intensive, to put it gently. If you're trying to run a local server, it requires more RAM than connecting to a remote. If you've got more available on your PC, try going into the FTB launcher settings and allocate more RAM to Minecraft.

On my PC I can run everything just fine with 3GB, but I've found that it seems to require a lot more if you're using a higher-res texture pack and whatnot. Adjust it up about 500MB at a time and see what happens.